# laravel trying to pluck received id, can't use it

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

What i want to achieve is getting few movie_id's from the MovieRating. and then find these id's in Movie. But i receive an error `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 25 column index out of range (SQL: select * from "movies" where "id" = 1)`

```
    public function index(){
        $movies = Movie::orderByDesc('id')->paginate(5);
        // <problem>
        $bestMoviesRatings = MovieRating::orderByDesc('average')->with('movie')->pluck('movie_id');
        $bestRatedMovies = Movie::where('id', $bestMoviesRatings)->get();
        // </problem>
        return view('movies/mainMovies', compact('movies', 'bestRatedMovies'));
    }
```

Does anybody know how to help me? thanks 4 help

Comment: `->with('movie')` also seems to be superfluous since you dont use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one because your variable $bestMoviesRatings is an array I think.

```
$bestRatedMovies = Movie::whereIn('id', $bestMoviesRatings)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey I'm not 100% about your database stracture but I think should try whereIn insted of where

```
$bestRatedMovies = Movie::whereIn('id', $bestMoviesRatings)->get();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```php
$bestMoviesRatings = MovieRating::orderByDesc('average')->pluck('movie_id')->all();
$bestRatedMovies = Movie::whereIn('id', $bestMoviesRatings)->get();
```